# Allow HTML on Zend form elements

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, zend-form, socialengine

I have the following element in Zend form:

```
$this->addElement('Select', 'my_element', array(
  'label' => 'My Element',
  'description' => 'My link <a href="https://www.google.com/">here</a>',
  'multiOptions' => array(
    'opt_one' => 'Option One',
    'opt_two' => 'Option Two',
  ),
));
```

I have also tried to add `'escape' => true,` after 'multiOptions', but it does not take effect.
Any idea how I could make the HTML work in 'label' and 'description'.

Comment: This   `$this->getElement('my_element')->getDecorator('Description')->setOption('escape',false);`    seems to work, but it still seems a bit complicated. Any other ideas?

Comment: I afraid, but Zend_Form decorators cant be less complicated, this is one of most unpleasant features of ZF 1. Hate them when I learnt ZF some years ago. Well, still dislike them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do like this:

```
$select = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('my_element', array(
     'label' => 'My Element',
     'description' => 'My link <a href="https://www.google.com/">here</a>',
     'multiOptions' => array(
     'opt_one' => 'Option One',
     'opt_two' => 'Option Two'
)));

$select->getDecorator('Description')->setOption('escape', false);
$form->addElement($select);
```

Comment: Thanks. It works somehow, but it is not exactly ok, because I don't want to completely change the code, I would like to keep that format. Isn't there any other way?